# Get URL from Eclipse's internal web browser

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been having a hard time figuring this one out.
I'm writing a plugin in eclipse which launches Eclipse's internal web browser. So far I've opened up the internal web browser:

```
IWebBrowser browser = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().createBrowser(IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.LOCATION_BAR, null,"Expert Viewer", "Validation");
browser.openURL(new URL(some url));
```

and I want to get the url of the current page that is opened in the browser. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Is there any way to do that without using SWT browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using `IWorkbenchBrowserSupport` is that you're not guaranteed to get an internal browser back.  It may open an external browser if the internal browser is not available, or the workbench is configured to use it, etc.

If you know you always want an internal browser (and that you're only supporting platforms where the internal browser is always available) then you can forego the `IWorkbenchBrowserSupport` interface and simply use the `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` widget.  Then you can hook up a `LocationListener`, for example:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
browser.addLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
    public void changing(LocationEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Navigating to: " + event.location);
    }

    public void changed(LocationEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Location is: " + event.location);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the swt browser was my second idea as well. Do you know if the swt browser widget supports newer standars, i.e. html5, various plugins...

Comment: It depends on the platform - on Windows, this will be IE (and thus the version of IE you have installed), on Mac this will be Safari and on Linux this will either be Firefox or Webkit (depending on the version of Eclipse and what browsers you have installed.)  So it really depends more or less on your configuration.  We execute some checks in Javascript (using `Browser#evaluate`) to determine the browser's functionality to know if we can proceed.